# selenium xpath find a href with innerHTML with regex match

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to find all `a.href` elements where innerHTML match `Page [\d]+` ??

Like this

```
<a href="/something">Page 1</a>
<a href="/something">Page 2</a>
<a href="/something">Page 97</a>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `//a[starts-with(., "Page ")]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny solution is to get all elements using this locator (if you expect that some href could start with 'Page ' and include not digits after it):

```
driver.findElements(By.xPath("//a[@href][number(substring-after(text(), 'Page ')) > 0]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPath for your findElements call:

```
"//a[text()[contains(.,'Page')]]"
```